# Attach kubernetes object to Helm release

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Using elastic official Helm chart, to deploy an elasticsearch cluster.

I had to create some k8s objects such as a NetworkPolicy in addition of the Helm `values.yaml` file.

I am wondering if it's possible to "attach" this object to the Helm release, so I can delete it when doing `helm delete`?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.

Helm [uses](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/pkg/action/uninstall.go#L179) `$ helm get manifest <release-name> -n <namespace>` to list the items to delete. So, unless your objects are part of that list, you won't be able to delete them with `$ helm delete`.

Comment: One possible workaround: Customize your chart, add those object yamls to the template so that those objects become a part of the manifest, use that customized chart while installing and uninstalling.

Comment: yes I am afraid :/ I tried using annotation, no luke. In my case, extra k8s objects are coming from another project, no way to have it in the chart.